# Is it possible undelete DATASET in BigQuery?

Tags: dataset, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to *recover dataset* in **BigQuery** with all tables?

Comment: It's not the same thing--as far as I know, deleting a dataset is permanent (and first requires deleting all of the tables that it contains).

Comment: Yes, it's not the same problem. One thing is an undelete DATASET and other undelete TABLE in dataset.